# ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm doing a webscraping on a site and sometimes when running the script I get this error:

```
ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

My code:

```
url = 'mysite.com'
all_links_page = []
page_one = requests.get(url, headers=getHeaders(), timeout=10)
sleep(2)
if page_one.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup_one = BeautifulSoup(page_one.content.decode('utf-8'), 'lxml')
    page_links_one = soup_one.select("ul.product_list") 

    for links_one in page_links_one:
        for li in links_one.select("li"):
            all_links_page.append(li.a.get("href").strip())
```

The answers I found was not satisfactory

Comment: nothing to do except increasing timeout in your call. Website have anti scrapping protection mechanism that would make your request hang if flagged as scrapper. Try other things like proxies

Comment: Even though I'm sending the headers, how am I still flagged as scrapper?

Comment: hard to debug the issue if you don't share the url. is it possible you can access through api?

Comment: You could get flagged as a scrapper based on time and/or timing. If the server sees too many requests from the same IP in set amount time, it could deem you a robot, or if the requests come at precisely timed intervals, etc... anything that could indicate non-human usage.

Comment: have you fight this? I have same problem, internet connection is good, timeout changing doesn't help me at all

Answer (score 14):

I was helped by increasing the timeout, immediately set 120 seconds. It turned out that the response from the server comes within 40 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have the timeout parameter in there? I would just eliminate the timeout parameter. The reason you get that error is because you set it to 10 which says if you don't receive a response from the server in 10 seconds, raise and error. So it's not necessarily the server calling you out. If no timeout is specified explicitly, requests do not time out (at least on your end).

```
page_one = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  #< --- don't use the timeout parameter
```

Comment: Am I using this parameter to prevent site blocking, or am I wrong?

Comment: I believe it is always better to set timeout, server can keep a request hanging for quite a while specially if it suspects a bot, thus storing the link and requesting it later or using a proxy to ask again might solve it.

Comment: @wishmaster thats a good point. Probably better to increase the timeout parameter here then.

Comment: from the docs: [Nearly all production code should use this parameter in nearly all requests. Failure to do so can cause your program to hang indefinitely.](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts)

Comment: there's always timeout bcs by default timeout is 300 s in any requests unless u override that

Answer (score 2):

This exception might occurs due to timeout or the available memory:

- The response from the server takes longer than the specified timeout. So to solve it you need to set a higher timeout.
- The file your are trying to read is large and the socket buffer is not enough to handle it. So you can try increasing the buffer size based on your machine's capacity.

```py
        import urllib3, socket
        from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection
    
        HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = ( 
            HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
            (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 1000000), #1MB in byte
            (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1000000)
        ])
```